# How to Refine HeavisideTheta or UnitStep?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, piecewise

Look at the following chunk of code:

```
Assuming[x > 0, Refine@HeavisideTheta[x]]
```

It yields `1`. However the same method does not work if `x` is an expression. The following commands returns the `HevisideTheta` unevaluated:

```
Refine[HeavisideTheta[V^2 - (χa - χr)^2/(a + r)^2], 
 V^2 - (χa - χr)^2/(a + r)^2 > 0]

Assuming[V^2 - (χa - χr)^2/(a + r)^2 > 0, 
 Refine@HeavisideTheta[V^2 - (χa - χr)^2/(a + r)^2]]
```

Simplify also does not work. Is it possible to evaluate this and similar expressions?

**Update**
I found a remedy that solves all my problems. Here it is:

```
c2Mono = Reduce[{V > 0, V^2 - (χa - χr)^2/(a + r)^2 > 0, 
   r > a > 0, χr > χa}, χr]
n2Mono = ....;

UnitRule = {(HeavisideTheta[x_] | UnitStep[x_]) -> 
   Piecewise[{{1, x > 0}, {0, x < 0}}]}

n2Mono = FullSimplify[PiecewiseExpand[n2Mono /. UnitRule], c2Mono]
j2Mono = FullSimplify[PiecewiseExpand[j2Mono /. UnitRule], c2Mono]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### 1. Modify `"AssumptionsMaxNonlinearVariables"`

If you set the option value for `"AssumptionsMaxNonlinearVariables"` (which is a sub-option of the system option `"SimplificationOptions"`)  to a number larger than the number of variables in your input expression (say, 10) you get the desired simplification:

```
SetSystemOptions["SimplificationOptions" -> {"AssumptionsMaxNonlinearVariables" -> 10}];

FullSimplify[HeavisideTheta[V^2 - (χa - χr)^2/(a + r)^2], V^2 - (χa - χr)^2/(a + r)^2 > 0]
```

> 1

```
FullSimplify[UnitStep[V^2 - (χa - χr)^2/(a + r)^2], V^2 - (χa - χr)^2/(a + r)^2 > 0]
```

> 1

You can replace `FullSimplify` with `Refine` and get the same results:

```
Refine[HeavisideTheta[V^2 - (χa - χr)^2/(a + r)^2], V^2 - (χa - χr)^2/(a + r)^2 > 0]
```

> 1

```
Refine[UnitStep[V^2 - (χa - χr)^2/(a + r)^2], V^2 - (χa - χr)^2/(a + r)^2 > 0]
```

> 1

The default value for this sub-option is 4:

```
SystemOptions["Simp*"]
```

> {"SimplificationOptions" -> {"AssumptionsMaxExponent" -> 25, 
>      "AssumptionsMaxNonlinearVariables" -> 4, 
>      "AssumptionsMaxVariables" -> 21, "AutosimplifyTrigs" -> True, 
>      "AutosimplifyTwoArgumentLog" -> True, 
>      "ConvertTrigsToRadicals" -> False, "FiniteSumMaxTerms" -> 30, 
>      "FunctionExpandMaxSteps" -> 15, "ListableFirst" -> True, 
>      "RestartELProver" -> False, "SimplifyMaxExponents" -> 100, 
>      "SimplifyToPiecewise" -> True}}

To reset the option to its default:

```
SetSystemOptions["SimplificationOptions" -> {"AssumptionsMaxNonlinearVariables" -> 4}]
```

#### 2. Use `PiecewiseExpand`:

For `UnitStep`, `PiecewiseExpand` using assumptions in the second argument works:

```
PiecewiseExpand[UnitStep[V^2 - (χa - χr)^2/(a + r)^2], V^2 - (χa - χr)^2/(a + r)^2 > 0]
```

> 1

For `HeavisideTheta` it does not:

```
PiecewiseExpand[HeavisideTheta[V^2 - (χa - χr)^2/(a + r)^2],
   V^2 - (χa - χr)^2/(a + r)^2 > 0]
```

> HeavisideTheta[V^2 - (χa - χr)^2/(a + r)^2]

So a simple approach is to replace the head `HeavisideTheta` with `UnitStep` before

```
PiecewiseExpand[# /. HeavisideTheta -> UnitStep, V^2 - (χa - χr)^2/(a + r)^2 > 0] & @
   HeavisideTheta[V^2 - (χa - χr)^2/(a + r)^2]
```

> 1